# Using slash character in Azure Service Bus entity names

Tags: azure, uri, special-characters, naming-conventions, azureservicebus

I'd like to group my related queues and topics and using slashes seems to be natural. It's an URI after all so `https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/{entity}/{command|event}` pattern would be nice to follow. But Azure portal disallows slashes when creating an entity:

> Service Bus entities cannot be created with '/' due to restrictions
>   with ARM. However, the backend will replace all instances of the '~'
>   character with '/' once the ARM layer has been circumvented, allowing
>   you to create new entities with '/' by creating them here with '~'.

However, you can perfectly create "slashed" names via the management API or Service Bus Explorer and the portal nicely displays them although with a warning:

> ARM does not support resource names containing the '/' character.
>   Service Bus converts these slashes to '~' when interfacing with ARM,
>   but retains the slashes in its backend. Your entities with slashes in
>   their names may appear with tildas instead in certain blades of the
>   Portal, but Service Bus supports and will continue to support these
>   resources with their original format with slashes.

I'm not sure I understand it. What are possible future consequences? Is it a good idea to ignore the warning and use slashes or just go with a neutral separator like a dot?

Comment: if the answer is not addressing your question, provide a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the ARM, or to be more accurate, how it expects the URI for a resource to be structured. It expects pairs with slash used as a delimiter. 
See this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/06/21/azure-service-bus-azure-resource-manager-and-this-character/) from the ASB team that explains the issue with ARM.

ServiceBus Explorer on the other hand uses `NamespaceManager` which doesn't have the same expectation as ARM has.

Bottom line: `~` is needed for ARM. To have your path segmented, it's a `/`. Based on the tooling you're using, make the required adjustment.

Comment: so is there not a way to have both the segmented path in servicebus explorer AND use arm?

For what it's worth, I've found that the azure CLI also doesn't support the '/' in `az servicebus topic create `